# Export data from client to server via postgresql ODBC

Tags: c, postgresql, odbc

I wish to upload my text data from client application to server database. Right now, i'm using `ODBC` to communicate with `PostgreSQL`. I use `ODBC` because there is a need to connect to multiple type of databases.

My issue here is, `PostgreSQL` uses `PQgetCopyData` to obtain the stdout data when using `COPY` OUT. So, is there any workaround to obtain the data from output stream without using `libpq API` and transmit it over by :

```
SQLExecDirect (hStmst,"COPY <table> FROM STDIN WITH CSV ",SQL_NTS)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have two options.  The first is to use the old `COPY` command (borrowed from Quel interestingly enough).  The second is to use a CSV parsing library of your choice and generate INSERT statements.

The tradeoff is that `COPY` will work MUCH faster, whine `INSERT` will work on other databases too.